# Does system.Decimal use more memory than 'decimal'?

Tags: c#, struct, uppercase, lowercase

I heard someone say that in C#, capital Decimal is using more memory than lower case decimal, because Decimal is resolved to the lowercase decimal and that requires memory.

Is that true?

Comment: Hm. Question (1807368) created as a certain user; question deleted; question re-created as a rather anonymous user again. Interesting.

Comment: shared computer still logged in as a certain user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

`decimal` is simply an alias for `System.Decimal`. They're exactly the same and the alias is resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not true.

The `decimal` keyword is an alias for the type `System.Decimal`. They are the exact same type, so there is no memory difference and no performance difference. If you use reflection to look at the compiled code, it's not even possible to tell if the alias or the system type was used in the source code.

There is two differences in where you can use the alias and the system type, though:

- The `decimal` alias is always the system type and can not be changed in any way. The use of the `Decimal` identifier relies on importing the `System` namespace. The unambiguous name for the system type is `global::System.Decimal`.
- Some language constructs only accept the alias, not the type. I can't think of an example for `decimal`, but when specifying the underlying type for an enum you can only use language aliases like `int`, not the corresponing system type like `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's just silly.

In C#, decimal is just a synonym for Decimal. The compiler will treat decimal declarations as Decimal, and the compiled code will be  as if Decimal was used.

Comment: With all due respect, it isn't "silly" - it is a perfectly valid question, especially if you come from a java background where the difference is boxed vs unboxed - i.e. a big difference. It **happens** that in C# they are the same.